# Listing expired SQL logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, security

For audit purposes, we need to list all SQL logins with their creation and expiration dates. Is there a way to script this for all of my SQL Servers, rather than performing the task manually through the UI?

Answer (score 2):

To get the information for a single instance you would use `DaysUntilExpiration` value for the `LOGINPROPERTY` function. This will give you the days until the password expires. You can then cast that as an integer and use the `DATEADD` function to get the actual date.

```
SELECT name AS LoginName, 
   DATEADD(DAY, CAST(LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'DaysUntilExpiration') AS int), GETDATE()) AS ExpirationDate,
   create_date
   FROM sys.server_principals
   WHERE type = 'S'
```

Now you can use a few different methods to get this from multiple servers:

- Multiple instance connection via SSMS and Registered Servers
- PowerShell using the `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet within the SQLPS snapin. AS long as you are on a machine with SQL Server 2008 (or higher) management tools, this is available.

Examle:

```
$q = @"
SELECT name AS LoginName, 
DATEADD(DAY, CAST(LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'DaysUntilExpiration') AS int), GETDATE()) AS ExpirationDate,
create_date
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE type = 'S'
"@

Add-PsSnapin *SQL*

$serverList = 'Server1','Server2','Server3\InstanceName'

foreach ($s in $serverList)
{
 Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $s -Database master -query $q
}
```